# Union 2 lists with additional content change for ID that occurs in both source lists

Tags: linq

How to merge these 2 collections?

Problem:  When an ApplicationID is in listOfPM and listOfPM2, Test2 is null and should be a number

```
var listOfPM = from d in gbc
                select new Tab24PresentationModel
                {
                    ApplicationID = d.ApplicationID,
                    ApplicationName = d.ApplicationName,
                    Test1 = d.count,
                    Test2 = null
                };


var listOfPM2 = from d in gbc2
                select new Tab24PresentationModel
                {
                    ApplicationID = d.ApplicationID,
                    ApplicationName = d.ApplicationName,
                    Test1 = null,
                    Test2 = d.count
                };


var result = listOfPM.Union(listOfPM2);
```

Have tried removing the Test2 from list of PM and Test1 from listOfPM2 from each and get:

> The type 'xxx.Tab24PresentationModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

I can think of ways around this using multiple foreach's.. would like to use Linq!

Comment: omg... So many duplicates.  https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+combine+two+lists

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think his question is a bit specific, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Then edit the title to reflect that.

Comment: For the record, Linq is really `foreach` and `yield` under the covers anyway; your best solution might be to simply spend a dozen lines of code doing it in a `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and more descriptive title... d.count is simply an int.  d.CountOfTestIssues would be better.  Robert - thanks I've put in a solution in an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the answers and comments - here is what I came up with.

```
// take each list in turn and either add or update
var result = new List<Tab24PresentationModel>();
foreach (var t in listOfPM)
{
    var a = new Tab24PresentationModel
        {
            ApplicationID = t.ApplicationID,
            ApplicationName = t.ApplicationName,
            Test1 = t.Test1
        };

    result.Add(a);
}

// list2
foreach (var t in listOfPM2)
{
    // is this already in result
    if (result.Any(x => x.ApplicationID == t.ApplicationID))
    {
        var existing = result.First(x => x.ApplicationID == t.ApplicationID);
        existing.Test2 = t.Test2;
    }
    else
    {
        var a = new Tab24PresentationModel
            {
                ApplicationID = t.ApplicationID,
                ApplicationName = t.ApplicationName,
                Test2 = t.Test2
            };
        result.Add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the two objects (with same ApplicationID) manually, no way around that.

Edit - try this:

```
var list = gbc.Union( gbc2 ).ToLookup( d => d.ApplicationID ).Select( g =>
    {
        var first = g.First();
        var retVal = new Tab24PresentationModel
        {
            ApplicationID = first.ApplicationID,
            ApplicationName = first.ApplicationName,
            Test1 = first.count,
            Test2 = null
        };

        var second = g.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

        if( null != second )
        {
            retVal.Test2 = second.count;
        }

        return retVal;
    } );
```

Edit 2: hrm, that would only work if you don't want `Test1 = null, Test2 = value` when only the gbc2 exists.  If that's not an issue, you should be ok.